# nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands

Tags: wifi

I have setup 3 raspberry pis as wifi access point using Realtek RTL8188CUS wifi dongles, and it worked like a charm.
I'm following the adafruit tutorial mostly (https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point.pdf).
This was in november & december 2015.

yesterday I tried the exact same process (3 times), exact same hardware, same configuration and I get this error:

> nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands

What could be the problem. Could it be a compatibility problem with the new version of Raspbian jessie?
Any idea of what I could do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my problem. I needed to update hostapd.

After trying out several ones, the one that worked was the adafruit one. 
http://adafruit-download.s3.amazonaws.com/adafruit_hostapd_14128.zip

It had worked without when I setup the AP in november, but not this time.

Still interested in understanding why..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Edimax EW-7811Un USB dongle.

I was powering Raspberry Pi from my Macbook Pro. Turns out USB port on the left side of Macbook might not give enough power. When I switched to USB port on the right side of Macbook everything magically worked again.

Comment: keep in mind that you need good amount of current to power the Pi 2 and a WiFi Adapter. So in the future use a stand-alone power cable with a minimum __2 Ampere__ current rating.